# Promise inside cron job not executed

Tags: javascript, typescript, cron, promise

I have the piece of code in typescript that have a very strange behaviour
I wrote some code that apparently is OK but I have a very strange behaviour.
After I get loggedIn to a service I want to start a CronJob.

```
SomeService.login()
    .then(() => {
        // new CronJob(expression, workFunction, null, true);
        workFunction();
});

function workFunction() {
    console.log("start")

    Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => startSomething())
        .then(moreStuff1)
        .then(moreStuff2)
        .then(moreStuff3)
              ...
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(errorHandling);
}
```

This code works fine for me if I just call the workFunction like it is right now, but if I switch the code to use the CronJob, it will call the function but the promises inside will not be resolved.
The first .then is called and the next ones are ignored and the return of the function startSomething() will be printed in the last .then()

I dont know if this is related to the fact that the CronJob is started from inside a Promise.then() but I see that the workFunction is being called on each tick, which is correct.

**FIXED**

I could fix it by binding the workFunction to this.

```
new CronJob(expression, workFunction.bind(self), null, true);
```

Comment: I had a similar issue once, due to missing environment variables. Check: http://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work  and http://2clickfix.com/6-reasons-cron-job-not-running/

Comment: by the way ... `Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => startSomething()).then(...` is just `startSomething().then(...`

Answer (score 1):

It seems this behavior is somehow related to the execution context of the cron job. I don't understand it but it seems to be different in some way. I guess breaking out of this context with a timeout solves the problem:

```
function wrapper() { setTimeout(workFunction) }

new CronJob(expression, wrapper, null, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have a `return` missing in your `workFunction`?

```
SomeService.login()
    .then(() => {
        // new CronJob(expression, workFunction, null, true);
        workFunction();
});

function workFunction() {
    console.log("start")

    return Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => startSomething())
        .then(moreStuff1)
        .then(moreStuff2)
        .then(moreStuff3)
              ...
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(errorHandling);
}
```

Comment: Hi Alistair, the workFunction should not return anything. But I also tried that before.